# Computing the product of big numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm trying to compute

[image: problem],

where C<sub>i</sub> is the i-th Catalan number.

To solve the problem, I loop from 0 to n and sum the product of two Catalan numbers:

```
BigInteger catalanSum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
                catalanSum += catalan(i) * catalan(n - i);
```

The catalan function is returning the binomial coefficent divided by n + 1:

```
    BigInteger catalan(int n)
    {
        return NchooseK(2 * n, n) / (n + 1);
    }
```

And to compute the binomial coefficient I use this function:

```
    BigInteger NchooseK(int n, int k)
    {
        BigInteger res = 1;

        if (k > n - k)
            k = n - k;

        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        {
            res *= (n - i);
            res /= (i + 1);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

It works fine up to n = 1000, but as soon it get highers it really slows down alot. Is there any way I can optimize this calculation?

EDIT:

I sped up the computation by saving the catalans first using the following code-snippet, thanks to xanatos answer:

```
BigInteger[] catalans = new BigInteger[n+1];
            BigInteger catalanSum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
                catalans[i] = catalan(i); 
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
                catalanSum += catalans[i] * catalans[n - i];
```

EDIT 2:
When catalan[i] == catalan[n - i], wouldn't the remaining half of computations have the same product as the first half?

Comment: You should save catalan(n) to reuse it as catalan(n - 1) in the next cycle. This will halve the time.

Comment: Use recursion with a classic recursive function?

Comment: @xanatos Thanks, see my edited question

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Not sure what you mean, but I've tried to calculate binomial using recursion and it's way slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

First, check OEIS for your sequence. You will find that the sequence has [an entry](https://oeis.org/A000108). And this entry has a useful formula:

```
2*(2*n-1)*a(n-1) = (n+1)*a(n)
```

So, calculating the Catalan numbers can be done much more efficiently:

```
BigInteger lastCatalan = 1;
catalans[0] = lastCatalan;    
for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
    lastCatalan = (2 * (2 * i - 1) * lastCatalan) / (i + 1);
    catalans[i] = lastCatalan;
}
```

The second thing is that your summation is symmetric. I.e., you just need to sum half of the entries:

```
BigInteger catalanSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (n + 1) / 2; i++)
    catalanSum += catalans[i] * catalans[n - i];
catalanSum = 2 * catalanSum;
if (n % 2 == 0)
    catalanSum += catalans[n / 2] * catalans[n / 2];
```

After גלעד ברקן  pointed out that the sum you are looking for is the `n+1`-th Catalan number, this can be simplified drastically:

```
BigInteger catalanSum= 1;
for(int i = 1; i <= n + 1; ++i)
    catalanSum = (2 * (2 * i - 1) * catalanSum) / (i + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

The computation you are describing seems like the first recurrence relation for computing the `n`th [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) (and you're needlessly applying a binomial computation as well when you could just use the Catalan numbers themselves in the recurrence). That's O(n^2) complexity plus the complexity for all the binomial computations. Why not use the second recurrence relation?

```
catalan(0) = 1
catalan(n + 1) = 2*(2*n + 1) / (n + 2) * n
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborate a bit on the subject? Or even better show me how I could implement that.

Comment: @acGunner see Nico's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also cache the factorials.

Comment: Do you mean something similar to what I did with the Catalan numbers?

Comment: Yes, exactly. To compute 1000 terms, you need factorials up to 2000. You'd avoid a lot of recomputations by storing them. It's worth a try.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Sorry about that. I'm new to stackoverflow and learning how it works.